# Replace values in multiple columns of dataframe with numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to replace values in multiple columns of a dataframe with `numpy.where` in Python by doing the following:

```
df['X, Y, Z'] = np.where(df['X, Y, Z'] < 1, 0, df['X, Y, Z'])
```

However, it gives me the following error: `KeyError: 'X, Y, Z'`

I have already tried doing the strings separately, like `'X', 'Y', 'Z'`, but it doesn't work either.

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about passing a proper list of keys `['X', 'Y', 'Z']` to your dataframe instead of a long string `'X, Y, Z'`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = {'X': np.linspace(0,2,8), 'Y': np.linspace(0,2,8)*2, 'Z': np.linspace(0,2,8)*4}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

which gives:

```
>>> df
>>> 0  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
>>> 1  0.285714  0.571429  1.142857
>>> 2  0.571429  1.142857  2.285714
>>> 3  0.857143  1.714286  3.428571
>>> 4  1.142857  2.285714  4.571429
>>> 5  1.428571  2.857143  5.714286
>>> 6  1.714286  3.428571  6.857143
>>> 7  2.000000  4.000000  8.0000000

df[['X', 'Y', 'Z']] = np.where(df[['X', 'Y', 'Z']] < 1, 0, df[['X', 'Y', 'Z']])
```

and now with no longer `KeyError`:

```
>>> df
>>> 0  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
>>> 1  0.000000  0.000000  1.142857
>>> 2  0.000000  1.142857  2.285714
>>> 3  0.000000  1.714286  3.428571
>>> 4  1.142857  2.285714  4.571429
>>> 5  1.428571  2.857143  5.714286
>>> 6  1.714286  3.428571  6.857143
>>> 7  2.000000  4.000000  8.000000
```

Comment: I'm sorry but this solution seems a bit confusing to me. I find it weird because my method works if I only put 'X' as the column instead of all three, so I don't know why that's happening.

Comment: `df['X', Y', 'Z']` is not the same as `df[['X', 'Y', 'Z']]` that is why. In one dimensional case `df['X']` is indeed the same as `df[['X']]`. Python doesn't split `'X, Y, Z'` and interpret it as 3 distincts keys nor it does understand 3 distincts keys, but it needs to iterate through list of keys `['X', 'Y', 'Z']`one at a time, hope it's clear now.

Comment: I understand why my method doesn't work, but the method you use still confuses me. The weird thing is that I remember my code working last week where I used this same method with multiple columns on the same dataframe, so I don't know what I did different now.

Comment: Will do. Can you maybe just explain why you choose the values 0,2,8 and the multiplying with 2 and 4 part?

Comment: In order to generate small dummy columns of `8` samples that span a range between `0` and `2` where your test condition is meaningful (since you failed to provide a Minimal Reproducible Example). I multiplied by `2` and `4` to get different columns where the condition applied differently. This is arbitrary but shows you that it works for various data :)